# Fantasy series with young red-headed female protagonist, past lives, multiple dimensions, elemental magic

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the book series a long time ago. Hopefully the bits I remember, listed below, are enough to go on.

- From memory there are three or four books in the series and I read them in the mid 2000's, in English, and they were pitched at a youth/young adult level though not afraid to tackle some serious issues (fairly sure there is a main character death at some point)
- The main character was a girl in her teens (name potentially beginning with an 'A' and maybe tied to the name of one of the books and/or the series?) and she had red hair
- She was human and living in modern times and ended up mixed up in a bunch of conflict in multiple other worlds or dimensions (I think the first time she got dragged into it she had been exploring out the back of her house and there were portals or gateways under the hill) and developed various powers/magic through the books and obviously ended up having to save the world
- She ends up having had previous lives and during the series she gets access to the memories from the previous lives
- May have been some form of time travel included
- There were a number of other races in the novels who inhabited the other worlds, and there was elemental magic around
- There was a floating mountain at some point I think, and dragons

Comment: How long ago was "a long time ago"? Also, in what language did you read this?

Comment: I think it was around 10 years ago, mid 2000's sometime, and they were in English!

Comment: Hey! Please make sure to read our [Story-ID guide](http://Scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and then [edit] any details into your post. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance it could be His Dark Materials by Philip Pulman ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials

Comment: Unfortunately not, though I've read those and loved them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Alosha](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765349604)** by Christopher Pike?

More here (and a different cover) in a previous question:

[2000s fantasy book with a red-haired protagonist meeting companions from her previous life, including a troll](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/name-of-a-fantasy-book-with-a-red-haired-protagonist/103660#103660)

> While hiking in the woods behind her house, Ali stumbles across a plot by the elementals--mysterious creatures who live in a neighboring dimension--to invade and destroy the Earth. Not only that, she discovers that she has been chosen to stop the attack.
>
> Why Ali?
>
> It is very possible that she is more than human . . .
>
> Eager to earn her magical abilities and learn her true identity, Ali sets out on a great adventure.
>
> Accompanied by a devious leprechaun, a loyal troll, and three close friends, Ali strives to reach the top of a forbidden mountain and lay claim to the Yanti, an ancient talisman of great power that even the elementals cannot control.

[image: floating mountains]

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure about some elements, since I've read only the first book, but this might be the Red Moon Trilogy of YA novels, by Micah Caidin.  In the first one *Time Trap*, a teen girl with no memory of her own identity (except her name) or origin is captured in what appears to be our own world, in Nevada side of the Sierra Nevada, and taken to a school for "special" youths, where she is pulled through a computer screen with two others into a world with a red moon, very dangerous dragon-like beasts and burrow up from under the ground, and a connection to a far future Earth.  She has to find her way back in a limited time, while protecting the two boys who were drawn through with her.

The follow-ons might well include a floating mountain.

Comment: Sounds intriguing but while the books seemed set in modern times, tech never featured heavily as far as I can remember - no computer screen portals

Answer (score 4):

The French author Pierre Bottero wrote a set of book called "Quest of Eliwan" ("La Quête d'Ewilan" in french) (3 books) with a second set called "Worlds of Ewilan" (3 books also), and a spin-off "Ellana" (3 books again) that match your description.

- The main character (Ewilan) is a young girl with red hair. She lives in Paris. She perform magical act or go to other world by "drawing" in her mind. One of her first time she tried to escape an auto accident and arrived in the other world.
- Her (true) parent where missing, supposed dead.
- several other race in the magical world
- The second set of book treated of an opponent that was using our (technical) world to stage an attack on the magical world, and controlling other mages that use lower-level/brutal magic
- In the spin off there is a mountain that appears to float (high in the cloud)

On the other side, I can't recall any dragon.

Comment: Not it unfortunately! I'm fairly sure that the series was originally written in English and the 'drawing' aspect doesn't ring any bells

Answer (score 3):

Longshot, but this could Traci Harding's series about Tory Alexander. "**The Ancient Future**" is the first one.

It fits many details you provide. Except:

1. Her hair colour, it could have been red but I'm not sure.
2. I don't remember a dragon. Although one of the characters is known as "The Dragon of The Isle".
3. A floating mountain, but I only read the first book out of six.

Everything else sort of matches though.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *The Chronicles of Amber*?

> *The Chronicles of Amber* is a series of fantasy novels by American
>   writer Roger Zelazny. The main series consists of two story arcs, each
>   five novels in length. Additionally, there are a number of Amber short
>   stories and other works.
>
> The Amber stories take place in two "true" worlds: Amber, and the
>   Courts of Chaos, as well as the shadows that lie between them. These
>   shadows, including our Earth, are parallel worlds that exist in the
>   tension between the two true worlds of Amber and the Courts. The
>   Courts of Chaos are situated at the very edge of Abyss itself. Royals
>   of Amber who have negotiated the Pattern can travel freely through the
>   shadows. By shifting between shadows, one can alter or create a new
>   reality by choosing which elements of which shadows to keep, and which
>   to subtract. Members of the Courts of Chaos who have traversed the
>   Logrus are also able to travel through shadow.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia, *The Chronicles of Amber*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)

Comment: Amber certainly has multiple worlds, but it doesn't have a female protagonist (both Corwin and Merlin are male), nor does it have a young adult feel.  I also don't remember a floating mountain and dragons weren't a significant part of the books.

Comment: That's not it, but they look interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be Tiffany Aching series of books, part of the Discworld series by Terry Pratchett?

> Tiffany begins her witching career at nine, upon being scouted out by
>   the "witch finder" Miss Tick. She leads the Feegles on a journey into
>   Fairyland to rescue Wentworth, her sticky toddler brother, as well as
>   Roland, the young son of the local Baron, from the Queen of the Elves.
>   For this she earns the respect of Granny Weatherwax, a not
>   insignificant achievement in itself. Although at the time she is too
>   young to be a witch, Granny gives her an imaginary invisible hat to
>   boost her confidence. Such is the power of belief on the Disc that it
>   actually keeps off the rain. Two years later she travels to Lancre to
>   be formally apprenticed to the witch Miss Level. During her time with
>   Miss Level, Tiffany uses a charm "see me" to exit her body and see
>   herself, believing it to be a harmless charm.[11] Her body becomes
>   vulnerable to infestation by a "hiver," (a gestalt entity of minds
>   from the dawn of time) which uses her power to harm and cause chaos.
>   She eventually manages to overcome the hiver by giving it what it
>   truly wants: the ability to die.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia article for Tiffany Aching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_Aching)

Old baron dies in third book. There's some flame and ice magic in second one. There is time travel in 3rd book.

There is indeed a floating mountain and dragons in Discworld, but not in the Aching parts. They show up in *The Colour of Magic*, the first book in the Discworld series:

> The trio visit the Wyrmberg, an upside-down mountain which is home to
>   dragon-riders who summon their dragons by imagining them, and are
>   separated when the riders attack them. Rincewind escapes capture but
>   is forced by Kring, Hrun's sentient magical sword, to attempt to
>   rescue his friends. Twoflower is imprisoned within the Wyrmburg, and
>   because of his fascination with dragons, is able to summon one greater
>   than those of the Wyrmberg riders, who he names Ninereeds, allowing
>   him to escape captivity and save Rincewind from being killed in a duel
>   with one of the three heirs of the Wyrmburg.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia article for *The Colour of Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_of_Magic)

Comment: Unfortunately not! Though I do love Pratchett, in particular the ones focused around Tiffany